# My Api is accepting Content-Type application/json as headers. I set Header perfectly as mentioned in Retrofit Docs

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

```
@POST("SchoolAdminWS/services/auth/parentPortal/login")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<PasswordLoginResponse> passwordLogin(@Field("userName") String userName, @Field("password") String password);
```

But in Request Log it is Returning Content-Type txt/html.So how i should fix this issue? This api works fine in POSTMAN

Comment: Something here is weird - using `@FormUrlEncoded` should make the request content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, not text or json. Do you mean the response content type? Do you have raw logs to look at, see exactly what's being sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Just added  header and post the parameter on Body 
So the call is.

```
    @Headers("content-type: application/json")
    @POST("SchoolAdminWS/services/auth/parentPortal/login")
    Call<PasswordLoginResponse> passwordLogin(@Body Map<String, String> body);
```